# If called from Main class returns empty value

Tags: java

Main class:

```
package com.home.dhe;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Display q = new Display();
        q.getinfo();
        Getname z = new Getname();
        z.print();
    }
}
```

Display class:

```
public class Display extends Getname{

     public void getinfo() {
            System.out.println("Enter name");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            String d = sc.next();
            System.out.println("Marks?");
            int c = sc.nextInt();
            Getname z = new Getname();
            z.change(d, c);

        }
    }'
```

Getname class:

```
public class Getname {


    private int marks;
    private String name;

    public void change(String a, int b){

        name = a;
        marks = b;
        }

    public void print(){

        System.out.println("Student info");
        System.out.println("marks:"+marks);
        System.out.println("Name:"+name);
    }

}
```

My problem is when I call the `print()` method (from the `Getname` class)
 from Main class it returns a null value. But when I call it in from another class it works.

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: Well you're calling `print` on a *new instance* of `Getname()`. If you call `q.print()` instead, that will work...

Comment: Remove this `Getname z = new Getname();` since `Display` inherits it.

Comment: That design looks odd anyways. `Display` already extends `Getname` so why does `getinfo()` create a new local instance ( `Getname z = new Getname();`) instead of calling `change(...)` on itself? And why do you create yet another instance of `Getname` for printing?

Comment: Thanks guys, I have 1 more question though, when I create a new instance of a class, (Getname z = new Getname();), is the old instance wiped out or is it still usable? What I'm asking is does every object have its  own instance of the class? Sorry if the question is too Noob

Answer (score 1):

You are discarding the `Getname` instance created by `q.getInfo()`. What you probably want to do is return the `Getname` instance from `q.getInfo()` and use that to print.

```
public class Display extends Getname {

    public Getname getinfo() {
        System.out.println("Enter name");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String d = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Marks?");
        int c = sc.nextInt();
        Getname z = new Getname();
        z.change(d, c);
        return z;
    }
}
```

Then in the `main` method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Display q = new Display();
    Getname z = q.getinfo();
    z.print(); // This will print the values set by q.getInfo()
}
```

Overall, I think you may have some design problems that should be fixed.

Comment: Instead of returning a `Getname` it would be smarter to basically to set the fields on `Getname` to protected and manipulate it directly. Since you know it's inheritance after all.

Comment: Thank you Sir, I appreciate your help. PS: is there a book or something u recommend I read to solve the design problems u mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

both marks,name instant variables in class Getname need to be initialized, otherwise, the default values will be assigned to them : zero for integer and null for String.

Comment: or you can change your main code to be like this                                 Display q = new Display();  q.getinfo(); q.print(); without creating new(unintialized) instance then calling its print method